# how to insert variable values in link href using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

just want to ask if how to add a variable in the href? 
for example this is the my javascript:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        function setLinkValue(value) {
            var numItems = $('[id^=site-]').length;

            for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) { 
                var link = document.getElementsByClassName('site-link');
                link.href = link.href.replace('putNatsvarHere', value);
            }

        }

        //You would pass netsvar here
        setLinkValue('ExampleValue');

    });
</script>
```

I want to insert it into my `a` tag in href

```
<a href="http://websitelink.com/track/putNatsvarHere/pt?thumb_id=302&gn=pt&gi=01.jpg" id="site-link" class="title" target="_self">Exclusive February Sale!</a><br>

    <a href="http://websitelink.com/track/putNatsvarHere/pt?thumb_id=302&gn=pt&gi=01.jpg" id="site-link" class="title-link" target="_self">Sale!</a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://websitelink.com/track/putNatsvarHere/pt?thumb_id=302&gn=pt&gi=01.jpg" id="site-link" class="title-link pink-play" target="_self"> February Sale!</a>
```

Comment: you can use onClick attribute and call getCookie method

Comment: How i gonna use that? can you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace a segment in the URL with the value, and you don't even need jQuery to do it. See the working example below.

```js
function setLinkValue(value) {
  var link = document.getElementById('site-link');
  
  link.href = link.href.replace('putNatsvarHere', value);
}

//You would pass netsvar here
setLinkValue('ExampleValue');
```

```html
<a href="http://websitelink.com/track/putNatsvarHere/pt?thumb_id=302&gn=pt&gi=01.jpg" id="site-link" class="title-link pink-play" target="_self">Exclusive February Sale!</a>
```

You could call `setLinkValue` in this way:

```
var natsvar = getCookie("nats");
setLinkValue(natsvar);
```

To update multiple elements, you could use `getElementsByClassName` and loop through them.

```js
function setLinkValue(link, value) {
  link.href = link.href.replace('putNatsvarHere', value);
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('title-link');
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  //You would pass netsvar here
  setLinkValue(elements[i], 'ExampleValue');
}
```

```html
<a href="http://websitelink.com/track/putNatsvarHere/pt?thumb_id=302&gn=pt&gi=01.jpg" class="title-link pink-play" target="_self">Exclusive February Sale!</a>
<a href="http://example.com/putNatsvarHere/" class="title-link pink-play" target="_self">Another link</a>
```

Comment: It didnt work for me. but i think this is the way i wanted to happen

Comment: the link on my send became link this
<a href="http://websitelink.com/track/putNatsvarHere/pt?thumb_id=302&gn=pt&gi=01.jpg" id="site-link" class="title-link pink-play" target="_self">Exclusive February Sale!</a>

instead the value of putNatsvarHere

Comment: can you help me @drew?

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday I'm not sure what you're asking. If you run the snippet in the answer, you can see that `putNatsvarHere` in the link becomes `ExampleValue`, which in your case would be the value of the cookie instead.

Comment: I think it was only applied in one link? i tried but it look only one link has changed.

Comment: I want to apply to all links.

Comment: This answer still applies in that case. You just need to get all relevant links and loop through them, with something like `getElementsByClassName`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: actually i tried a loop. but it didnt work? I will update the code above so that you can check it?

Comment: @SheerwoodJohnCaday See my update. There are multiple issues in your code: element IDs must be unique, you must use a class name, not an ID, for `getElementsByClassName`, and you aren't actually looping through the elements, but retrieving them all every time. Really this should be in a new post, so please ask a new question if you have further issues. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks a lot @drewgaynor you help me. so sorry, i am not so good at javascript.